# Why can't I learn how to Implement the ONVIF standard?

Tags: web-services, networking, soap, network-programming, wsdl

I've bougth an IP camera. I then, discovered that it uses a standard called ONVIF. I searched about it and saw that it's a good way to put all the cameras in the world to be implemented in the same way.

Of course I've read the ONVIF specification PDFs. What I understand about how it works, is the following:

There is a WSDL file that describes how the camera (or another thing) can be accessed. Like, which settings can be modified, which methods are accepted, and so. When I read this WSDL file, I'll choose a method and send a type of message called SOAP, which will be a XML containing the response to some method on the WSDL file. SOAP is a XML that can go over HTTP (so it can go through firewalls), but also can be sent over other protocols.

So, as I understood, if I want to tell my camera to start streaming video, I just need to find the WSDL method that describes how to initiate a stream, and then send a SOAP message to tell it that I need to start a video stream over some protocol, at some port. Then, I can read and decode the stream.

By knowing this simple example I gave, I could do other things, like, control the camera and so. I don't know the public for which the PDFs at ONVIF are directed for, but I couldn't understand it enough so I could explore my camera. For example: I don't know how to receive this WSDL file. I've read somewhere that I should access http://ip_of_camera/onvif/device_service to get the file, and then I should send a SOAP message to it and watch the response.

I even tried to analyse the packets via wireshark, but they've seem nonsense to me. It was difficult because I couldn't even make my camera work with iSpy software. It only works perfectly (but with no audio or talk) in my android app, so I've set up a proxy at my raspberry pi and then analyzed the packets.

Could somebody give me a basic example of how to receive the WSDL file, and then how to call one method of it? I wanted to see how it works in a network level, but I can only find how to call libraries in C# that are ready to deal with it.

For example: I wanted to know what I need to send through TCP or over TCP/HTTP to the camera, and how to initate a stream. All of this in network level, no code needed at all.

I'm just trying to learn here, but this doesn't seem like a real "open" standard. It's very hard to understand if you never programmed anything like it. So I guess those PDFs are for people who work with it. I know how TCP and UDP works and how to send raw messages by them, so it's all a question of finding a good resource with examples, so I can understand what ONVIF is really about.

Couldn't the internet unite to make it more clear? Why there are no posts about it?

Thanks, amazing community <3

Comment: ps: networking level, no code, no libraries, that's not learning

Comment: Here [on github](https://github.com/Sufi-Al-Hussaini/onvif-gsoap-by-example) is some code I wrote for getting a snapshot from an ONVIF compliant IP Camera that others may find useful. The code uses the gsoap toolkit & is well commented, and should be easy to follow.

Comment: I also need to know how to implement ONVIF on android and iOS but I can't find a proper way on the Internet, can anyone help?